# Bootstrap ScrollSpy reseting position after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have problem with bootstrap scrollspy function.

For example when i akcept something, that will run reload function, my scrollspy element have to be at the same position like before, but it doesn't work for me. He just refreshing position.

I tried to change something in scrollspy.js from bootstrap order but that doesn't help me or maby i changed something at wrong position in code.

So, im looking for javascript or jquery solution to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var refreshScrollSpy = function (element, navElement, offset) {
// cache current scroll position to come back after refreshing, in your 
// case you can save your old position in this variable.
var cacheScrolltop = $(element).scrollTop();
   $(element)
     .scrollTop(0)
     .scrollspy(‘refresh’)
     .scrollTop(cacheScrolltop);
};
```